# VHDL: Why are 2 dimensional vectors initialized like nested 1 dimensional vectors?

Tags: multidimensional-array, syntax, vhdl, array-initialization

In VHDL arrays (vectors) can be initialized by using `(others => <element>)`.

1-dimensional example:

```
signal mySignal1 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
```

If I'm using two nested 1-dimensional vectors, it looks like this example:

```
type myVector is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal mySignal2 : myVector(3 downto 0) := (others => (others => '0'));
```

OK, and here is the true 2-dimensional example:

```
type myMatrix is array(natural range <>, natural range <>) of std_logic;
signal mySignal3 : myMatrix(3 downto 0, 7 downto 0) := (others => (others => '0'));
```

So as it can be seen, the signal has a different structure then the previous one, but the initialization is the same.

Why is/was not this syntax: `(others, others => '0')` used/chosen?

Comment: The two syntactically identical aggregates are distinguished by type, which for an aggregate comes from the enclosing context. Adding another complication for aggregate formats seems unwarranted - think about rules for others choices in multi-dimensional indexes.

Answer (score -1):

Because the comma "," in the construct (others, others => '0') implies that the two terms are scalar elements of a vector.  They aren't.  (others => (others => '0')) is the only fully unconstrained nested vector construct VHDL has.